# Separating exponential terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Suppose I have a lot of expressions multiplied by factors such as:

$$e^{-i\theta[1]-i\theta[2] - i\theta[3]-i\theta[4]-i\theta[5]}$$

I would like to separate this into a product of exponentials of the form

$$e^{-i\theta[1]}e^{-i\theta[2]}...$$

before employing the function `ExpToTrig` and making substitutions to the result trigonometric functions.

However, since I plan to apply the tangent half angle substitution (cf. my previous question [Simplifying Expressions for FindMinimum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89637/simplifying-expressions-for-findminimum)), I would like the arguments to involve only one variable at a time. In particular, I tried using `ComplexExpand` on the function to express the trigonometric functions as functions of a single variable, but it expands the entire function out.

In short, I would like to keep the simplified form, but want to expand the exponential as per the above without having to expand the entire expression.

For reference, here is my function

```
(E^(-I θ[1] - I θ[2] - I θ[3] - I θ[4] - I (θ[5] - θ[6]))
Abs[Sin[ϕ[6]]]^2 (1 - E^(I (θ[1] - θ[6]))
   Cot[ϕ[6]/2] Tan[ϕ[1]/2]) (Cos[θ[1]] + I Sin[θ[1]] + E^(I θ[2])
   Tan[ϕ[1]/2] Tan[ϕ[2]/2]) (Cos[θ[2]] + I Sin[θ[2]] + E^(I θ[3])
   Tan[ϕ[2]/2] Tan[ϕ[3]/2]) (Cos[θ[3]] + I Sin[θ[3]] + E^(I θ[4])
   Tan[ϕ[3]/2] Tan[ϕ[4]/2]) (Cos[θ[5] - θ[6]] + I Sin[θ[5] - θ[6]] - Cot[ϕ[6]/2] 
   Tan[ϕ[5]/2]) (Cos[θ[4]] + I Sin[θ[4]] + E^(I θ[5])
   Tan[ϕ[4]/2] Tan[ϕ[5]/2]))/
(2 Sqrt[(1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[1]/2]]^2) (1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[2]/2]]^2)]
   Sqrt[(1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[2]/2]]^2) (1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[3]/2]]^2)]
   Sqrt[(1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[3]/2]]^2) (1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[4]/2]]^2)]
   Sqrt[(1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[4]/2]]^2) (1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[5]/2]]^2)]
   Sqrt[(1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[1]/2]]^2) (1 + Cos[ϕ[6]])]
   Sqrt[(1 + Abs[Tan[ϕ[5]/2]]^2) (1 + Cos[ϕ[6]])])
```

Comment: As you can see by entering E^a E^b, Mathematica automatically translates those into E^(a+b). Thus even if you transform the result back into E^a E^b Mathematica will immediately put it back. It is possible to stop this, but perhaps not simply and conveniently.

Comment: Possibly you can get the desired effect by doing `TrigExpand[ExpToTrig[...]]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60761/41148

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Update

In the interest of simplifying the code somewhat, I've modified one of the replacements. For instance, we can do

```
expr2 = Thread[expr1, Plus] /. Plus -> Times
```

or

```
epxr2 = expr1 /. expT[Plus[a__]] :> Times @@ expT /@ a
```

rather than

```
expr2 = expr1 //. {expT[a_ + b_] :> expT[a] expT[b]}
```

So:

```
f[expr_] := Thread[expr /. Power[E, a_] :> expT@Expand@a, Plus] /. Plus -> Times /. expT[a_] :> ExpToTrig@Exp@a
```

or

```
f[expr_] := expr /. Power[E, a_] :> expT@Expand@a /. expT[Plus[a__]] :> Times @@ expT /@ a /. expT[a_] :> ExpToTrig@Exp@a
```

#### Original Post

As `Bill` commented, Mathematica likes to keep `Exp[]`'s together. Here's a workaround that I've used in the past. We replace `Exp` with a dummy head `expT`, do the re-write using replacement rules, and in the process apply `ExpToTrig`.

For instance, if

```
expr = Exp[-I (4 + a) + c];
```

we first do

```
expr1 = expr /. Power[E, a_] :> expT@Expand@a
(* expT[-4 I - I a + c] *)
```

Then, we separate the terms inside `expT` using `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
expr2 = expr1 //. {expT[a_ + b_] :> expT[a] expT[b]}
(* expT[-4 I] expT[-I a] expT[c] *)
```

Finally, we convert back to `Exp` and apply `ExpToTrig`:

```
expr2 /. expT[a_] :> ExpToTrig@Exp@a
(* (Cos[4] - I Sin[4]) (Cos[a] - I Sin[a]) (Cosh[c] + Sinh[c]) *)
```

We can do all at once, of course. Define

```
f[expr_] := expr /. Power[E, a_] :> expT@a //. {expT[a_ + b_] :> expT[a] expT[b]} /. expT[a_] :> ExpToTrig@Exp@a
```

in which case

```
f[expr]
(* (Cos[4] - I Sin[4]) (Cos[a] - I Sin[a]) (Cosh[c] + Sinh[c]) *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing. Is there a way to apply this function on to the above expression in a consistent way? When I apply it directly it still returns trigonometric functions as functions of sums of variables, and when I try to use the mapping method: expr/.Exp[z_]->f[Exp[z]], it also does not work. Is there a way to apply this function to turn the expression above into one purely in terms of trigonometric functions of single variables without having to expand?

Comment: One way is to take the first term and re-write it as `E^(-I (\[Theta][1] + \[Theta][2] + \[Theta][3] + \[Theta][
    4] + \[Theta][5] - \[Theta][6]))`. Then in the first step use `expr1 = expr /. Power[E, Times[Complex[0, -1], a_]] :> expT@a`. This removes the imaginary number. Stick it back in step 3. `expr3 = expr2  /. expT[a_] :> ExpToTrig@Exp@(I a)`

Comment: @user238194. I think we just need to apply `Expand`. See the updated answer.

Comment: @march That works and doesn't require any manual intervention. Very nice piece of work.