# Replace pattern for exponentials

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

Ultimately, I want to replace every Exp[(const) w[i,j]] to T[i,j] and Exp[-(const) w[i,j]] to 1/T[i,j] in the following expression

```
(-1 + (E^(w[1, 0] - 1.55432 w[1, 1]) - 
E^(-w[1, 0] + 1.55432 w[1, 1]))^2/(E^(w[1, 0] - 1.55432 w[1, 1]) +
 E^(-w[1, 0] + 1.55432 w[1, 1]))^2)
```

However, when I use the replacement rule

```
/. (E^(x[i_, j_] w[i_, j_] + x[m_, l_] w[m_, l_]))-> (E^(x[i, j] w[i, j]) E^(x[m, l] w[m, l]))
```

as an intermediate step, the replacement does not do anything on the expression. Any suggestion?

Thanks,
SJS

Comment: *Mathematica* automatically simplifies `Exp[a] Exp[b]` to `Exp[a + b]`. You if you make an intermediate step where you replace `E` by `exp` (lowercase is important!), then do your replacement (or something like it) with `exp` in place of `E`, it should work. Alternatively, you could wrap the expression with `Inactivate` or something. See my [answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/90056/29734) for one possibility.

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = (-1 + (E^(w[1, 0] - 1.55432 w[1, 1]) - E^(-w[1, 0] + 1.55432 w[1, 1]))^2 /
             (E^(w[1, 0] -  1.55432 w[1, 1]) + E^(-w[1, 0] + 1.55432 w[1, 1]))^2)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr /. Power[E, Plus[x_, y__]] :> Inactive[Times][Power[E, x], Power[E, y]]/. 
    {Power[E, Times[c_, w[i_, j_], ___]] :> Power[T[i, j], Sign[c]],
     Power[E,  w[i_, j_]] :>T[i, j]} //Activate
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For version 9:

```
expr /. Power[E, Plus[x_, y__]] :> times[Power[E, x], Power[E, y]] /. 
      {Power[E,   Times[c_, w[i_, j_], ___]] :> Power[T[i, j], Sign[c]], 
       Power[E, w[i_, j_]] :> T[i, j]} /. times -> Times
```

Update: A slightly more general form allows arbitrary number of terms in the exponent:

```
f = # /. Power -> power /.  power[E, x : PatternSequence[___]] :> ( 
     Times @@ (power[E, #] & /@ x)) /. 
     {power[E, Times[c_, w[i_, j_], ___]] :> Power[T[i, j], Sign[c]], 
      power[E, w[i_, j_]] :> T[i, j]} /. power -> Power &
f @ expr
```

> same output as above

```
 expr2 = (-1 + (E^(w[1, 0] - 1.55432 w[1, 1] + 2 w[1, 2]) - 
   E^(-w[1, 0] + 1.55432 w[1, 1] - 3 w[3, 1]))^2/
    (E^(w[1, 0] - 1.55432 w[1, 1]) + E^(-w[1, 0] + 1.55432 w[1, 1]))^2)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f @ expr2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was also having similar problem, @kglr. How is it extended to the case when one has more than two terms in each of the exponentials? Say, the number of terms is arbitrary and not known a priori?

Comment: @dbm, good question. I will post an update if i can come up with a generalization.