# Replacing exponential pattern in equation

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I have an equation of  the form

```
f=a0+a1*Exp[-b1*x]+a2*Exp[-b2*x]+a3*Exp[-b3*x]+...+an*Exp[-bn*x]
```

with $n$ exponential terms. $a_i,b_i$ are real numbers (a result of some previous computation). My intention is to apply integral operator $\int_p^qdx$ to the function above. When number of terms in above equation becomes very large (in fact on my PC about greater than 30), the evaluation becomes very slow. So I thought why not bypass the integration step and use replacement rules because I know what the integral is going to look like. That is I want to do the following replacement, which I hope will speed up evaluation:

```
Exp[-b*x] -> (Exp[-b*q]-Exp[-b*p])/b
a0 -> a0(q-p)
```

I want to repeat that $a_i,b_i$, are real numbers which are output of some previous computation, and not just symbols, even though for generality I had to represent them as symbols here rather than as numbers.

I wish I could tell you what I tried, but honestly I have no clue how to proceed with this problem. How do I match patterns and do replacement in this case? Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. I saw this post: [Replace pattern for exponentials](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114170/replace-pattern-for-exponentials) but wasn't helpful to me.

Comment: You say the $a_i$ are real numbers. How do these numbers relate to the $a$ in your rule `a -> p - q`?

Comment: Why do you want `a->p-q`? `Integrate[a Exp[-b x], {x, p, q}]` yields $\frac{a \left(e^{-b p}-e^{-b q}\right)}{b}$.

Comment: @m_goldberg,  corey979 Sorry $a$ should be replaced by the quantity you have shown.

Comment: @corey979, m_goldberg The operator is $\int_p^q dx$, so the replacement for _constant_ term should be $a0\to a0(q-p)$. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = 3. + 2.6 Exp[-7.1 x] - 2.2 Exp[2 x]

rule = {Exp[b_*x] -> (Exp[b*q] - Exp[b*p])/b}

f /. rule /. {First[f] -> First[f] (p - q)}
```

[image]

The `First[f] -> First[f] (p - q)` is not very robust, though; works for this particular *type* of `f`.

Comment: +1 Beautiful. I guess I can always use ReplacePart for dealing with the constant term.

Answer (score 0):

Working with version 10.1 this seems to works perfectly

```
f = a0 + a1*Exp[-Subscript[b, 1]*x] + a2*Exp[-Subscript[b, 2]*x] + 
  a3*Exp[-Subscript[b, 3]*x]
Exp[-b*x] -> (Exp[-b*q] - Exp[-b*p])/b
```

Comment: I would add one element to the rule and apply it: ` rule = {Exp[-b_*x] -> (Exp[-b*q] - Exp[-b*p])/b, a0 -> a0 (p - q)};
f /. rule`

Comment: That's not an answer to this question, it doesn'r work on `f = 3. + 2.6 Exp[-3.7 x]`. The OP emphasized that `a, b` are some known particular numbers. @AlexeiBoulbitch's comment works, but partially, as it does not alter the `a`s.

Comment: @corey979  Right. This rule is better: `rule = {Exp[b_*x] -> (Exp[b*q] - Exp[b*p])/b, a0 -> a0 (p - q)};`.

Comment: I'm not fully awaken yet, but I think the OP wants sth like `rule = {a_ Exp[b_*x] -> (p - q) (Exp[b*q] - Exp[b*p])/b}`.

Comment: @corey979 You are right. Is     {a_Exp[b_*x]}  a valid pattern?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Thanks. Your answer was partially correct.