# Separate exponentials

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

Good afternoon,
I have an expression

```
Exp[2 I (t - tau) + a] + 2 Exp[2 I t + b] + 3 Exp[-I t + b]
```

And I want to write it as a summation of powers of Exp[I t]. So,

```
3 Exp[b] Exp[-I t] + Exp[2 I t] (2 Exp[b] + Exp[a - 2 I tau])
```

What is the way to do this?
I had several attempts including

```
Collect[%, Exp[I t]]
```

But that gives me only part of what I need:

```
3 Exp[b - I t] + Exp[2 I t] (2 Exp[b] + Exp[a - 2 I tau])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE! Can you explain what is your desired expression? As far as I can see `Collect` is giving you a similar one which you want!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separating exponential terms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90055/separating-exponential-terms). Also, there are many others question on manipulating exponentials on this StackExchange, so try searching among them :)

Comment: @codebpr I also want Exp[b-I t] -> Exp[b]Exp[-I t].

Comment: `Collect[expr, E^(I*t)] /. Exp[c1_ + c2_*t] :> Inactive[Times][E^c1, E^(c2*t)]`